# Define List(Of T) at declaration

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

Is it possible to have a compound declaration of a `List(Of T)` wherein the size of the list is specified and the list is populated with the objects of type T with default values?

For example, when T is `Integer` we can do the following for short lists:

```
Public MyList As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1, 2, 3})
```

But if I try the following for a longer, non-trivial object, list:

```
Public MyList As New List(Of MyClass)(New MyClass(100) {})
```

It seems the list is not populated with instances of `MyClass` and attempts to write to the items results in the exception:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Why should one work and not the other?

(I know I can add objects individually using the `Add()` method but there must be a neater way of setting up an array of specified size of default-valued empty objects [which is actually what I want], right?)

EDIT: In my use case MyClass is a simple data only (at the moment) class like

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Value As Byte
    Public Shadow As Byte
End Class
```

Maybe using a struct instead might be easier FWIW?

Comment: "but there must be" why? Also, that's not the error I get: which version of VB.Net are you using?

Comment: OK so the structure works FWIW _at the moment_. I'm still interested to see if the `List(Of MyClass)` is possible as I may need to switch the structure to a class in the future

Comment: @Richard I guess there doesn't _have_ to be but creating a list and then having to loop through every `Item` to add it's object when the objects all have the default values is just... clunky. .NET 4.5

Comment: Downvoters: what was wrong with my question? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a compound declaration of a List(Of T) wherein the size of the list is specified and the list is populated with the objects of type T with default values?

Yes. But (at least in the 4.5.2 framework and VS2013's VB.Net<sup>1</sup> version) the number of initialisers needs to match the capacity being set:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x = New List(Of Integer)(100) {1, 2, 3, 4}
    Console.WriteLine(x(0))
End Sub
```

gives:

> Array initializer is missing 97 elements.

However:

> ```
> Public MyList As New List(Of MyClass)(New MyClass(100) {})
> ```
>
> It seems the list is not populated with instances of MyClass and attempts to write to the items results in the exception:

You need to create the objects. The creation of `MyList` will have 100 elements but they will all be `Nothing` (`null`). You need to create the objects to use the members of `MyClass`:

```
MyList(0) = new MyClass();
MyList(0).Value = 42
```

> Maybe using a struct instead might be easier FWIW?

Based on this question: no it will not be because that natural syntax (eg. the assignment to the `Value` member above) will not give you the results you expect. Structs are copied, so with structs that statement would only change a copy of the struct instance and not the instance in the collection.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't keep track of VB.Net's version numbers.

Comment: Re structs: If I do away with the list, declare an array like so `Public MyArray(100) As MyStruct` and access by `MyArray(0).Shadow = 5` then surely the first struct on the array will have 5 in its member `Shadow`?

Comment: @Toby No it won't, when you access the element of the list a copy of the struct is made, and you assign to the property of the copy. Structs are assumed to be immutable.

Comment: Note I said, *array* of structs not, as you've said, *List* does that make a difference? If not is there any use to be had from an array of structs? Apologies, I am coming from a background in C and ASM and some of the rules of VB seem to be pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @Toby the collection (or even as a field/property's type) makes no difference. Collections of structs work fine if you do not change their values (they are immutable).

Comment: Also, as regards creating the objects for the list, I assume in the integer example, that `(New Integer() {1, 2, 3})` Creates the Integers for the List so it seems illogical that `(New MyClass(100) {})` would create only 100 `Nothing`s. Ah well :D

Comment: @Toby No it is completely logical. The default value for entries in the collection is `default(T)` (C# syntax: don't know the VB.Net equivalent). For value types that is zero initialise, for reference types it is `Nothing` (null).